# Why is the BEST algorithm so slow for modeling the difference in means of two vectors?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian

I'm using the BEST package in R as a proxy for the frequentist t-test to measure the difference in means between two groups.

However this process is VERY slow, and will simply not converge for the tests that I am trying to run. Is there another method that can work for this? I'm mainly looking for a Bayesian equivalent to a standard t-test.

Comment: How big are your n's? How long does it take? Also, can you give more details about what your situation is? Do you want to exactly replicate what BEST does, or do you just need something vaguely like it? There's not really enough information here to give good advice. I imagine a decent implementation of MCMC on this problem shouldn't be so terribly slow unless the sample sizes are huge (in which case, some approximation might suffice).

Comment: @Glen_b My n's are in the 10,000+ range each. I don't need to necessarily replicate what BEST does but I am looking for a Bayesian substitute for something akin to a t-test. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: So in effect you want a posterior distribution for the difference in means?

Comment: @Glen_b yes that would work. I was looking for a Bayesian 'drop-in' substitute for a t-test in comparing the difference of two means and my research took me to the BEST package. I'm not completely familiar with Bayesian Decision Theory.

Comment: BEST assumes the *data* are t-distributed, while a t-test assumes the data are normal. BEST uses normal priors on $\mu$'s, uniform on $\sigma$'s, and exponential on $\nu$'s. Do you need normal-data, t-distributed data, or will something else more heavy tailed than normal be okay? If you do need t-distributed data, do you need those specific priors? Do you need to deal with unequal variance, or is common variance okay?

Comment: Looking at Kruschke's paper, I'm not sure why it's slow; I think the mean and variance steps of an MCMC algorithm should be fast (at least if we implement it with an eye for avoiding unnecessary recalculation; that might be hard in JAGS). The $\nu$'s may well be inherently O(n), however -- but even then I can't see why it would be *particularly* slow. ... I think that if you just want a pretty straight Bayesian version of the ordinary t-test (say ... normal data, equal variance, conjugate priors), we can do that pretty easily, but you should specify more precisely what you do want.

Comment: Also, you should say as much as you can about your priors. Without looking at your data, what do you already know about your variables? (Or if you want less informative priors you should still say how you want to set them up --- should $\mu$ be centered at 0, for example? Should it be infinite-variance or finite variance?)

Comment: Not that the priors should make much difference, so if you don't care I can just do something simple.

Comment: How slow is it (seconds, minutes, hours, days...)? The package uses JAGS (as Glen_b noted) - you could try coding it in Stan and check if it works faster (because the code gets compiled and Stan uses different sampling algorithm). The models is pretty simple so it *should* work pretty fast (as for MCMC).

Comment: @Glen_b Could you provide the 'simple' example you were talking about? I don't really know enough about this topic to tell you about finite/infinite variance and so on. Perhaps if you just state your assumptions and give me a sketch of how to approach the problem then I would be able to modify it in the future.

Comment: I outlined the steps involved in doing the simple case that in my answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

To first address the title question:

In effect that depends on implementation details. A more specialized implementation may well be faster.

Because BEST uses $t$ distributions for data, I don't think there's are simple summary statistics for the mean or variance parameters (this contradicts what I was suggesting in comments earlier). So each of those calculations will be at least O(n) (every new $\nu$ would require a recalculation of likelihood / conditional distributions across the whole sample).

This might be why it's slow.

--

Here's one example of how to tackle a straight/simple ('drop in') "Bayesian t-test", in this case framed as a regression-on-a-dummy problem that should be about as fast as a single simulation-step of MCMC.

Take the set-up [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression#Conjugate_prior_distribution) and following the derivation [further down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression#Posterior_distribution), where in this case $\beta$ can be regarded as $(\mu_1,\delta)$, where $\delta$ is the difference in means ($\delta = \mu_2-\mu_1$) and $X$ is a column of 1's and a column, $g$, which is the 0-1 indicator for membership in the second group.

Then the posteriors given there can be computed once (no actual matrix inversion is required, I think, but even if it was, it's only 2x2). We can integrate $\sigma^2$ out of the posterior for $\beta$ to get a marginal for $\beta$.

Indeed, it looks like you could integrate $\mu_1$ out, then $\sigma^2$ and get what appears to be a closed form (I think $t$-distributed) posterior for $\delta$ alone involving no simulation at all.

It doesn't have to be done as a regression of course -- you can do the same calculations more directly. [I set it up that way because the calculations are largely already done for you.]

Some slightly more complicated cases can still be done along similar lines. Further complications may be easier done using MCMC -- but in at least some of those cases the calculation can be kept to simple summary statistics which should still result in fast iterations. (If that's still too slow, you might be able to get somewhere via Laplace approximation. There are a number of other possibilities)